# Productivity features in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have recently upgraded to VS2010, and overall I must say that I'm very impressed. I used to use ReSharper when working with VS2008, but I have found that many of it's features have been incorporated into VS2010. 
One of the features I like the most is the CTRL+, command which lets you navigate to a class or method by writing part of its name.
However, I have not had the time to explore all the new features, so I'd be really greatful if some of you would share the ones you like most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like **Call Hierarchies**

With Control+K and Control+T you can navigate the code likes reflector does but with the source code

[image: Call Hierarchies]
<sub>(source: [dotnetslackers.com](http://dotnetslackers.com/images/articleimages/vs2010-and-net-framework-4-ide-enhancements-part-1-8.png))</sub>

Also a great feature is **T-SQL IntelliSense**

A long requested feature that will become really :)

[image: Intellisense]

Answer (score 3):

Things I like:

- Several .NET 4 features, especially including:

  - New ["characteristics" of the reflection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217470/why-do-assembly-and-module-have-no-publicly-defined-constructors) that made one of my projects possible
  - Concurrent collections and the parallel extensions
  - More powerful expression trees
  - System.ComponentModel.Composition (home of the Managed Extensibility Framework)
  - [Windows 7 Shell APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell(VS.100).aspx)
- Editing improvements:

  - Improved IntelliSense selection algorithm (substring and CamelCase matching)
  - [Column editing](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/26/box-selection-and-multi-line-editing.aspx)
  - C++ improvements 1000X
- Other:

  - The entire environment can be colored. It's not trivial, but I imagine someone will make a nice extension that makes it easy.
  - MEF extensibility and VSIX packaging for extensions
  - The profiler keeps getting better